# Date Failure in Google App Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm maintaining a script which I should execute on a monthly basis. The script is running on 2588 URLs within a column in google sheet and retrieving the Last Modified Date Property from each one of them and outputs the dates into a new column from the right. The proposed is to measure the gap between the current date and last modified date of each URL.

In the example below you can see that the script is running on the D column URL list. The first 36 URLs are good and the Last Modified date property is fetching correctly. But the rest of the file is showing the 31/12/1969 Date as the screenshot is showing below here:

[image: The Problematic dates]

After I've read some questions here, I understood that the date indicates a failure/0 due to some problem with the script.
[image: Google Apps Script Runtime Limitations]

My code is as follow:

```
    function modifiedGap() { 
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  //The Google sheet to access
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Fund List");
  //The array of URLs to check
  var urls = sheet.getRange("D2:D2588").getDisplayValues();

  for (var i = 0 ; i < urls.length; i++) {
    var startTime= (new Date()).getTime();

    if (urls[i].toString() != '') {
      //Converting each URL to string and retrieving its Properties into a new Array
      var url = UrlFetchApp.fetch(urls[i].toString());
      var tweets = url.getAllHeaders();

      //Forming an array of Properties by Keys & Values
      var userProperties = PropertiesService.getUserProperties();
      userProperties.setProperties(tweets);
      var tweetsKeys = Object.keys(tweets);

      //Retrieving the link modification date from the property meta-data & outputs it as a String to the cell from the right respectivley.
      var date = new Date(userProperties.getProperty(tweetsKeys[7]));
      sheet.getRange(i + 2, 13).setValue(date);
    }
//    if (isTimeUp(startTime, Math.max(averageExec, execTime)) === true) {
//      autoTrigger(execProperties);
//      throw new Error('Script reseting');
//    }
  }
}

//
//function isTimeUp(start, need) {  
//  var cutoff = 500000 // in miliseconds (5 minutes)
//  var now = new Date();
//  return cutoff - (now.getTime() - start.getTime()) < need; 
//}
```

It seems that the URL are varying in response time and some aren't responding. Hence the script is crashing. Can someone elaborate on what should I do to skip these exceptions?

Comment: Have those actually been modified? It looks like the date value retrieved there is 0 which in your timezone would be that date.

Comment: Hi, I've checked one link where it shows 31/12/1969 and its modified date wasn't 0..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have added seems to check for the 6 minute limit as opposed to the 20000 fetch calls or 50000 PropertyService read/write calls you highligted in the screenshot.

The code block you use to prevent the 6 minute limit seems a bit off to me. You try to check if 30 milliseconds have passed. As an example here is my code that executes at the end of each loop:

```
if (typeof execProperties.nextPageId !== 'undefined' && execProperties.nextPageId) {
  if (isTimeUp(startTime, Math.max(averageExec, execTime)) === true) {
    autoTrigger(execProperties);
    throw new Error('Script reseting');
  }
}
```

where

```
function isTimeUp(start, need) {  
  var cutoff = 500000 // in miliseconds (5 minutes)
  var now = new Date();
  return cutoff - (now.getTime() - start.getTime()) < need; 
}
```

You can ignore the first if statement as it simply checks if we will even bother with another iteration. Simply at the end of the loop, check how long it took for the loop to execute once and update the average execution time of the loop, then compare the remaining time to the maximum allowed.

Comment: Hi Again @Vytautas, I'm running on the entire links column within that sheet and it's not debugging the code. it just stops the debug process with no error message/details. I have updated the code above to be the latest code that I've ran.

Comment: @TomerLevi make sure you have a break point set and uses step in. The break point cannot be on a `var` line, so set it on something like line with the `for` or `if`

Comment: Hi @Vytautas!, I have made some changes to my code. (you can see it above). Also, I inserted your function and if statement in quotes. Still, I didn't know how to calculate the amount of time for each iteration since its varies between each URL respond. I think that the best idea is to skip "problematic URLs" to keep the script running. Can you suggest how I should do it?

Comment: The only way to skip problematic URLs is if you try the same URL several times. If it's just once then there is no way. My code snipped is an example of how to do it, it won't work as a cut and paste. The idea is to know when you started with `var start = new Date()` and after each iteration of the loop have `var chkpoint = new Date()`. If `start` is when script started just make sure the difference between it and `chkpoint` is less than 5 minutes. If not, store where you are in script properties, create a trigger and terminate.

Comment: Hi Again @Vytautas.. I think I got it but since I'm not an expert: can you elaborate on this point? "If not, store where you are in script properties, create a trigger and terminate."

1. How to store my location in the script
2. how to create a trigger

Comment: @TomerLevi let's say you have array `urlList` and have a for loop go through `urlList[i]` and reach the time limit at `i = 55`. Use `PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty('index', i)` to store that. Create a trigger to run the function again and terminate the script with `return`. At the very start of the script check for the property. If it exists you need the `for` loop to start from `index+1` instead of `0` and delete the property (so it does not get in the way later). Read more [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties)

Comment: Hi @Vytautas! Thank you very much for the support it helped me a lot! It is working now and I think I have a little grasp now of how I can control my script. Thanks Again!